# Jsp out.print() captured extra text

Tags: java, jsp, printing

I have code fragment in my Jsp:

```
catch (Exception e) {
  out.print("<Grid><IO Result='-1' Message='");
  out.print(e.toString());
  out.print("'/></Grid>");
  out.close();
  throw new Exception("");
}
```

I expect that result must be valid xml as

```
"<Grid><IO Result='-1' Message='Failed to load HSQLDB JDBC driver.'/></Grid>"
```

But Result of this :

```
"<Grid><IO Result='-1' Message='");  out.print(e.toString());  out.print("'/></Grid>"
```

Please help me to fix this problem!

Comment: It's not the problem, but it's a ***really*** big assumption that `e.toString()` will only contain characters that are valid in an XML attribute, in particular one delimited using `'` characters.

Comment: I replaced e.toString() with "Some text". This did not help

Comment: @ user: *"It's not the problem, but..."*

Comment: I am a bit out of such JSP usage, but try backslash before apostrophe (`\'`). Maybe the JSP compiler played havoc. Look at the generated java source.

Comment: I also tried to use \' . Result is:

Comment: Something else. You might use apache commons StringEscapeUtils.escapeXML for the message.

Comment: "<Grid><IO Result='-1' Message=\'");  out.print(e.toString());  out.print("\'/></Grid>"

Comment: Another work-around: try `%><Grid><IO Result='-1' Message='%><%= e.getMessage() %><%'/></Grid><%`.

Comment: BTW, `out` is the original JspWriter? Not your own PrintWriter?

Comment: @Joop Eggen: Can you give a code piece?

Comment: @Joop Eggen: it is original

Comment: Maybe remove the close.

Answer (score 0):

```
catch (Exception e) {
    %><Grid><IO Result='-1' Message='%><%= e.getMessage() %><%'/></Grid><%
    throw new Exception("");
}
```

---

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<c:catch var ="e">
    ... // All
</c:catch>
<c:if test = "${e!=null}">
    <Grid>
        <IO Result='-1' Message='%><c:out escapeXML="true" value="${e.message}"/><%'/>
    </Grid>
</c:if>
```

Throwing I would leave for later.

Comment: now the Message attribute is "%><%= e.getMessage() %><%"

Answer (score 0):

The single quote in the first out.print() wasn't closed. Can you move the e.toString() up?

Edit: and escaping the single quotes as well?

```
catch (Exception e) {
 out.print("<Grid><IO Result=\'-1\' Message=\'" + e.toString() + "\'/>");
 out.print("</Grid>");
 out.close();
 throw new Exception("");
}
```

Comment: I also tried this. Message attribute became " + e.toString() + "